# Update an Array of NSManagedObjects

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm using CoreData and swift and trying to update an array of NSManagedObjects. However, I am receiving "Value of type '[NSManagedObject]' has no member 'setValue'" when I attempt to 
update both keys within the record in context.
I'm using the following line of code to perform the update:
"erManagedObject.setValue([(true, forKey: "aKey"),(false, forKey: "anotherKey")])"

```
public func updateRecordsForEntityManagedObject(_ entity: String, erManagedObject: [NSManagedObject]){
// Create the Fetch Request
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
let recordCount =  erManagedObject.count
     print(" Total Records: \(recordCount)")
     for i in 1...recordCount {
        // I receive the error here
        erManagedObject.setValue([(true, forKey: "aKey"),(DateUtilities().getTimestamp(), forKey: "timeStampKey")])
     }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 for i in 1...recordCount {
    // I receive the error here
    erManagedObject.setValue([(true, forKey: "aKey"),(false, forKey: "anotherKey")])
 }
```

With

```
erManagedObject.forEach { 
   $0.setValue(true, forKey: "aKey")
   $0.setValue(false, forKey: "anotherKey")
}
```

As you should use the loop item to `setValue` not the array itself

---

```
 let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:entity)

    do {
         let result = try context.fetch(request) as! [ModelName]
         result.forEach {
           $0.someKey = ""
         }
         // save context here  
     }
     catch {
       print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan, thanks so much for your suggestion. However I'm receiving "Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '([(Bool, forKey: String)])'" when I attempt to use it. Same error when I complete it with the actual parameters,

Comment: you can try edit , but it's better to cast your object as a model instead of using `setValue`

Comment: Thanks so much, Sh_Khan, after the following revisions to your suggestion, I'm able to get this to work.  erManagedObject.forEach { 
   $0.setValue(true, forKey: "aKey")
   $0.setValue(false, forKey: "anotherKey") do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("(UPDATE_ERROR) \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }

Answer (score 1):

erManagedObject is an array of NSManagedObjects. (Update) -- You are using the setValue method incorrectly, it should not take in an array. see Docs

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506397-setvalue

I think you want to do

```
erManagedObject[i].setValue...
```

Note: your for loop is going to crash because your array will be out of bounds.. your for loop should iterate from 0 ..< erManagedObjects.count

```
 for i in 0 ..< recordCount {
    erManagedObject[i].setValue...
 }
```

Alternatively...

```
for managedObject in erManagedObject {
  managedObject.setValue...
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Mocha I tried your first suggestion and am receiving the following error: "Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '([Any])'". Please note I did update the 2nd parameter. However, the error was received even when using the initial parameter.

Comment: Your setValue is wrong. You should not pass in an array. See doc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506397-setvalue

Comment: Thanks, @Mocha, given this, any suggestions regarding the entire record for the respective iteration if we don't use arrays?

Comment: I don't understand your question -- you can use the setValue method multiple times for multiple keys.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mocha. I've upvoted your suggestion.